# Validation in angular 2, not importing ControlGroup and Control related to form validation from @angular/common?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Hi I am new to angular 2 and angularcli please help me.

I have created form which need to validate. I am trying to import directives or services from @angular/common it showing error.
I am trying to access ControlGroup and Control from @angular/common.
for validation I am using FormBuilder

I am not getting what I am doing wrong

Here is my component typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {ControlGroup, Control} from '@angular/common'; //at this line the error is [ts] Module '"/home/Documents/newproject/mds/node_modules/@angular/common/index"' has no exported member 'Control'

@Component({
selector: 'app-formvalidate',
templateUrl: './formvalidate.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./formvalidate.component.css']
})
export class FormvalidateComponent {
  myForm:ControlGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = fb.group({
  firstname: ["", Validators.required],
  lastname: ["", Validators.required],
  usermail: ["", Validators.required],
  userpass: ["", Validators.required],
  userconfpass: ["", Validators.required]

});

}
}
```

Here is my HTML page which is contain form

```
 <div class="signin">
        <p class="login_subheading">Enter your information below</p>
       <form #sgnform="ngForm" ngSubmit(sgnform.value)>
        <div >
          <label>First Name<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"  ngControl="firstname" #firstname="ngControl">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!firstname.valid">This field is required</div>
        <div >
          <label>Last Name<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"  ngControl="lastname"  #lastname="ngControl">
        </div>
        <div >
          <label>Email Address<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input  type="email" id="usermail" class="form-control" ngControl="usermail" #usermail="ngControl">
        </div>
        <div >
          <label>Password<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input type="password" id="userpass" class="form-control" ngControl="userpass"  #userpass="ngControl">
        </div>
        <div >
           <label>Confirm Password<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input type="password" id="userconfpass" class="form-control" ngControl="userconfpass" #userconfpass="ngControl">
        </div>
          <div class="margintopbtm_30">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary modal_btn">Submit</button>
          <span class="required pull-right">*Required fields</span>
          </div>

         </form>
        <div class="footer_login">
        <span class="not_registered">Already registered?</span>
        <a class="btn sign-botton modal_btn pull-right">Sign in</a>      <br>
        </div>
  </div>
```

I have applied validation to view but i am getting error 
the error what i am getting is given bellow

```
zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngControl" ("/label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"    ngControl="firstname" [ERROR ->]#firstname="ngControl">
        </div>
             <div *ngIf="!firstname.valid">This field is re"):                     FormvalidateComponent@5:92
 There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngControl" ("/label>
          <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"      ngControl="lastname"  [ERROR ->]#lastname="ngControl">
        </div>
        <div >
"):FormvalidateComponent@10:92
```

My app.module.ts file is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { FormvalidateComponent } from './formvalidate/formvalidate.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    FormvalidateComponent
 ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
  export class AppModule { }
```

please let me where i am wrong. I am not getting what to do with this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things wrong

1. Don't try and use the forms from `@angular/common`. You should use the ones from `@angular/forms`. The analogue of `ControlGroup` in the `@angular/forms` is `FormGroup`. And the analog of `Control` is `FormControl`.
2. If you are going to use reactive forms, then you should import `ReactiveFormsModule` instead of `FormsModule`

   ```
   import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

   @NgModule({
     import: [ ReactiveFormsModule ]
   })
   ```
3. In your template, don't use `ngControl`, use `formControlName`.
4. In your template, pass the `FormGroup` to the `[formGroup]` directive

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
   ```
5. In your submit `ngSubmit(sgnform.value)`, it should be something more like

   ```
   (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
   ```

   You already have access to the `FormGroup` in the component, so you don't need to pass anything to callback. Also make sure you have the `onSubmit` method in your controller.

**See also:**

- [Cookbook: Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

Comment: hi it helps me a lot thank you I  have done same way and its working :)